# Forms authentication redirects back to Login.aspx after authenticating

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

Problem: Forms authentication appears setup correctly.  When running the following lines, the application is redirected back to the the login page.  No calls to other pages are made.

```
e.Authenticated = true;
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="180" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="xyz.com"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the web.config.  The test workstation where this was setup did not like the part...

```
domain="xyz.com"
```

Removing that made the entire thing work.